# Jasmine test explorer not showing test cases(it blocks) list in jasmine test explorer in visual studio code

Tags: typescript, protractor, jasmine2.0, jasmine-reporters

I am using Visual Studio code, Protractor, Typescript and Jasmine framework. I have spec test cases within "it" block.

To see all the test cases or it blocks I have installed "Jasmine Test Explorer
" and "Jasmine Explorer UI" but somehow test cases are not listed.

Could you please help me to resolve this.

[image]

Comment: Did you get it to work? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you solve this?

Comment: same issue. no tests are shown for me. Webstorm has it implemented by default. Would be nice to make it work on VSC.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a possible solution:

Create a setting pointing to your config file (e.g. in `.vscode/settings.json`):

```
{
  "jasmineExplorer.config": "jasmine.json",
  ...
}
```

In the `jasmine.json` file, you tell the explorer where the specifications are.  Here is an example:

```
{
    "spec_dir": "site/dist/tests",
    "spec_files": ["**/*[sS]pec.js"],
    "helpers": ["helpers/**/*.js"],
    "random": false,
    "seed": null,
    "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false
}
```

Comment: Where this jasmine.config locates?

Comment: @ChamilaMaddumage I improved the answer.  I incorrectly said `jasmine.config` where I meant `jasmine.json`.  Thanks for asking.

Comment: To add to this: The default location is normally `spec/support/jasmine.json` so you can just create the file there. I got it by clicking on the settings icon for Jasmine Test Explorer. Also, it's best to set your tests to random (a change from the listed file).

Comment: I had moved the jasmine.json to a different location...addition to `.vscode/settings.json` did the trick!

Comment: This answer is for JS files, the question asks about TS tests. Even by updating the file paths, it doesn't work for me. I can see JavaScript tests, but as soon as I add a TypeScript one, *all* tests disappear

Answer (score 4):

The Test Explorer plugin will not show any test if an error is encountered. To check if there were any errors during the compilation of your tests, go to the `Jasmine Explorer Log` in the Output tabs of VSCode (View -> Output)
[image]

You can see that in my case I was having an issue with module resolution that I fixed by tweaking `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: I cant even see this log item.

Comment: @CodeNameJack find (near the bottom) "jasmineExplorer.logpanel: Write diagnotic logs to an output panel called "Jasmine Explorer Log"" in https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-jasmine-test-adapter